# Eliminar hojas de phpexcel con nombres Worksheet

Tags: phpexcel

Estoy generando un informe de ventas y posteriormente lo exporto a excel 2007 a traves de PHPExcel. Todo sale bien pero al final me está generando varias hojas con el nombre de Worksheet segudios de un espacio con un número.

Encontré una función que me permite eliminar hojas e intenté esto:

```
$nombreFeuille = $excel->getSheetCount();
for($i=0; $i<=$nombreFeuille; $i++){
    $excel->removeSheetByIndex(
        $excel->getIndex(
            $excel->getSheetByName('Worksheet '.$i)
        )
    );   
}
```

Pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien tiene idea de como puedo eliminar todas esas hojas?

Compañeros, encontré un código donde alcanzo a encontrar y tomar el nombre de la hoja pero al utilizar la función `removeSheetByIndex` me arroja error.

```
// Obtener la cantidad de hojas en el archivo
$totalDeHojas = $excel->getSheetCount();
// Iterar desde la primera hoja hasta la última (índices de hoja comienzan desde 0)
for($indiceHoja=0; $indiceHoja<$totalDeHojas; $indiceHoja++){
    $hojaActual = $excel->getSheet($indiceHoja);
    //Obtengo el nombre de la hoja
    $nhoja = $hojaActual->getTitle();

    // verificar si el nombre comienza con 'Worksheet ' seguido de un número
    if (strpos($nhoja, 'Worksheet ') === 0 && is_numeric(substr($nhoja, 10))) {
        //Cuando entro acá, con un echo me doy cuenta que si hace la validación correctamente
        // Eliminamos la hoja
        //Pero cuando coloco el código para eliminar la hoja me sale error.
        $excel->removeSheetByIndex($indiceHoja);
    }
}
```

Estoy leyendo sobre la función `removeSheetByIndex` para tratar de entender el porque del error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compañeros, después de varios intentos combine las repuestas de @Goyo David Beaumont y @ Gaby Costilla y ya me funciona correctamente. Muchas gracias compañeros. Les comparto como quedó el código

```
// Obtener la cantidad de hojas en el archivo
$totalDeHojas = $excel->getSheetCount();
// Iterar desde la primera hoja hasta la última (índices de hoja comienzan desde 0)
for($i = $totalDeHojas - 1; $i >= 1; $i--){
    $hojaActual = $excel->getSheet($i);
    //Obtengo el nombre de la hoja
    $nhoja = $hojaActual->getTitle();

    // verificar si el nombre comienza con 'Worksheet ' seguido de un número
    if (strpos($nhoja, 'Worksheet ') === 0 && is_numeric(substr($nhoja, 10))) {
        // Eliminamos la hoja
        $excel->removeSheetByIndex($i); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes que hacer algún tipo de condición de este estilo dentro del for

```
$sheetName = $excel->getSheet($i)->getTitle()
// verificar si el nombre comienza con 'Worksheet ' seguido de un número
    if (strpos($sheetName, 'Worksheet ') === 0 && is_numeric(substr($sheetName, 10))) {
        // Eliminamos la hoja
        $excel->removeSheetByIndex($i);
    }
```

Comment: Hola compañero, agregué el código dentro del for pero me sale un un error. Estoy averiguando que otras funciones de PHPExcel puedo usar para obtener el nombre de la hoja y compararlo con el if como sugieres que me parece buena opción

Answer (score 0):

Podrias eliminar todas las hojas adicionales generadas por PHPExcel, al usar el siguiente código:

```
// Suponiendo que $excel es tu objeto PHPExcel

// Obtener la cantidad de hojas en el archivo
$nombreFeuille = $excel->getSheetCount();

// Iterar desde la primera hoja hasta la última (índices de hoja comienzan desde 0)
for ($i = $nombreFeuille - 1; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    $excel->removeSheetByIndex($i);
}

// Establecer la primera hoja activa (en este caso, la hoja original que necesitas)
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Este código eliminaria todas las hojas adicionales generadas y dejaria solo la hoja original como activa.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], recuerda dar crédito correspondiente para evitar "plagio".

Comment: Compañero, la situación es que estoy creando una hoja con el nombre de cada punto de venta, al ejecutar tu código me borra todas las hojas. Sólo necesito eliminar las que comienzan Worksheet. Estoy buscando la manera de obtener el nombre de la hoja para comparar. Gracias

Comment: Hola Gaby Costilla, puedes responder a la pregunta de @Marlon ?